# Convert CSV to JSON using Talend Open Studio for Data Integration

Tags: json, csv, talend, talend-mdm

I have the below CSV file format:

| title | studentName | studentID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Science | 'James','Jones' | 'JA002','JO101' |

I want to convert this to the below JSON format:

```
[{
"title": "Science",
"students":[
{
"studentname":"John",
"studentid":"JO12"
},
{
"studentname":"James",
"studentid":"JA23"
}
]
}]
```

How can I split the studentname and studentid in the CSV and convert it to the above JSON format using Talend Open Studio for Data Integration?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems to solve here :
First, splitting data so that Nth elements of your lists studentNames and studentIds match :
You can do this with tNormalize and tMap :
[image]

1. Just split on the comma in your studentNames field. If you have 2 studentNames, it will create 2 rows in output (vs 1 in input)
   2)Then it is a bit more tricky in tMap, you can use split method to create an array string, and access the Nth element in "studentId" list for each name
   [image]

Then you'll have to build the JSON in output, which is quite difficult with tWriteJsonFields component I think (it is doable but I don't like very much this component). You have 2 nested arrays, that could be quite a hassle to build with tWriteJson.

I did it with a tJavaFlex , placed right after tMap, and JSONArray/JSONObject objects.
[image]
Don't forget to import classes in advanced settings of tjavaflex

```
import net.minidev.json.JSONObject;
import net.minidev.json.JSONArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is **no** transformation needed, you should just be able to do the following:

```
tFileInputDelimited --> tFileOutputJSON
```

If there is **some** transformation needed, you might want to do the following:

```
tFileInputDelimited --> tWriteJSONField
```

Comment: If that’s possible then please show some output.